# Get record of Jan of current Year in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

How can we get record of first or second month of current year in MySQL query?

Like I want this data for January and then for February:

```
select Sum(amount) as Amount from tbl_incomes where created_at = 'here the month January OR February of current year should be claused'
```

Comment: As a side note, for most cases, you probably want to pass the current year as a parameter to your query, not let MySQL deal with "the clock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Amount 
FROM tbl_incomes 
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(created_at) IN (1, 2)
```

In case you want the `SUM` for January and February in separate rows you can use this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS Amount 
FROM tbl_incomes 
WHERE YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(created_at) IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
```

Comment: awesome, but can we get current year instead of typing the year?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a range expression.

```
SELECT sum(amount) amount
       FROM tbl_incomes
       WHERE created_at >= concat(year(now), '-01-01')
             AND created_at < concat(year(now), '-03-01');
```

That way an index on `created_at` can support the query.

Comment: You have an error, instead of `year(now)` you should use `year(now())`.